# detect if array value contains specific text PHP

Tags: php, arrays, html, sqlite

I have a SQLite- database containing articles. All articles contains HTML, but one of those articles contain an `<aside>`. So I'd like to present this article in another way than the others.

This is my code now:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$dbPath");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); // Display errors, but continue script


$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Article WHERE category = "article" ORDER BY pubdate DESC;');
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>


<table id="artikelLista">
  <caption><em>Visar alla artiklar</em></caption>


  <?php foreach($res as $article): ?>

   <tr class="artikelContent">
<td><h4><?php echo $article['title']; ?></h4>
    <?php echo $article['content']; ?>
    <span class="floatRight"><?php echo "Artikel skriven " . $article['author'] . " " . $article['pubdate']; ?></span></td>
  </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

  </table>
```

Is there a way to check if the `$article['content]` array value contains "`<aside>`" and set a different style for that tr? (Or div if this is not possible inside tr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
if(strpos($article['content'],"<aside>") == false) {
    //is <aside> is not present
} else {
    //if word detected
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The code above didn't detect `<aside>` with the tags, but it did detect it if I just put `aside` without the tags. Perhaps this code doesn't recognise text within HTML- tags?

Comment: No it should recognize the tags, it's just a string there is nothing special about having < or having > in a string.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I had made a stupid mistake in the code, it works just as it should! Thanks again! :)